# New SSL certs not being reflected on secure routes

Tags: openshift, openshift-origin

I am facing a problem, which I am unable to understand how to solve. I am using Openshift Origin 3.7, and have three routes corresponding to 3 deployments as follows (dummy data)

1) App 1 ---> www.domain.edu/

2) App 2 ---> www.domain.edu/path1

3) App 3 ---> www.domain.edu/path2

Since all the domain was the same, while configuring the secure route, I provided the same Certificate and private key on all these routes, and it worked great, until recently, when the certificate is due for renewal. I generated a new certificate, deleted the old routes and created new, identical routes, with the new certificate details.

But when I access the routes on my browser, still the older certificate is displayed. Am I skipping some step, which needs to be done. When adding the certificate, I only uploaded the certificate and key on the create route window and nowhere else. Do I have to redeploy the entire service etc.

Help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this problem. I just provided the certificate in the base app, and things started working.

Answer (score 0):

Solved this issue. I tried changing the Termination Type.

Previously the Termination Type was Edge. I changed it to Re-encrypt, added all the certificates then, reverted back to Edge. Somehow it worked. I don't know what was the main issue.